For any pair of distinct, real-valued bivariate samples of finite size n, can one always obtain one sample by some rotational function of the other?
I'd like to define a set of functions, $F$, with the following property. For every distinct pair of real-valued, finite, bivariate samples, $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$, there should be an $f$ in $F$ that rotates the former to obtain the latter, such that $f(X_1,Y_1) = (X_2,Y_2)$. Obviously, there can be no such $F$ for 2D rotations: otherwise, simply rotating the plot of any bivariate sample $(X, Y)$ continuously, would yield the plot of every other bivariate sample of equal length.
My question is whether such an $F$ exists for 3D rotations. Specifically, let $\Theta_n$ be the set of all possible, real-valued bivariate samples of finite size $n$, $\theta=(X, Y)$. Let $Z$ be an $n$-length vector of real numbers. Define 3D rotation matrix $R_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}$ as here, for angles $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.
Then $R_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}(X,Y,Z)$ rotates $(X,Y,Z)$ around the respective axes by the respective angles. Now, let $\theta_1=(X_1,Y_1)$ and $\theta_2=(X_2,Y_2)$ be any two members of $\Theta_n$. Does there exist some trio of real numbers $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and some real vector $Z$, such that $R_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}(X_1,Y_1,Z)=(X_2, Y_2,Z')$? (Note: it was pointed out that if we permit ties, the answer must be no. Given that ties occur with probability 0 for real-valued samples, however, let me make the practical revision: does such an $F$ exist "almost certainly"?)
If so, this implies one can define an $F$ with the above property, if every member $f_i$ applies a 3D rotation matrix for specified angles $(\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i)$ and a specified vector $Z_i$ of length $n$. In that case, must $F$ include functions with every possible trio of angles and every possible vector of $n$ values?
Bonus question: Does the answer generalize to multivariate samples beyond the bivariate case?
Edit: I originally asked: "If there is no $F$ for three dimensional rotations, does such an $F$ exist for rotations in higher dimensions $k > 3$? Say, for $k$ a function of $n$?" I've since realized the solution is trivial for $k$ = 4. Simply map $F$ to $\Theta$, so that each $f_i$ applies a rotation matrix to $(X_1, Y_1, \theta_i)$, with angles that flip from the $xy$-axis to the $uv$-axis.

I can't follow any of this, because I suspect my understanding of things like "sample," "observation," "rotate," and even what kind of mathematical object "$(X_1,Y_1,Z)$" is might differ from your intended meanings--and I suspect I'm not alone.  Would you please be so kind as to provide the simplest possible concrete example of what you mean by such a rotation?

I've tried to be precise, by giving specific definitions for "sample" and "rotation." Let me know if this is sufficient, or if an example is still required.

No.  Suppose sample 1 has 5 points at (1,1) and five points at (2,2) and sample 2 has 3 points at (1,1) and 7 points at (2,2).  They can't be rotated to be the same in any number of dimensions, because you can't undo ties.

Then I suppose I'd ask if we can define such an F "almost certainly" since ties occur with probability 0.

Just move the points slightly apart. Rotation is an isometry in 3-d and projection can only reduce distances.  (You didn't actually say these were from an absolutely continuous distribution)
